# reading a files which has several lines in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a file that has several lines like this:

```
(lp0
I200
aV<!DOCTYPE HTML
```

When I read this file in python, the file is read as it is, like this:

```
(lp0
I200
aV<!DOCTYPE HTML
```

but when i read it in pyspark, i got the following value:

```
(lp0\nI200\naV<!DOCTYPE HTML
```

How can I get the output of pyspark read to its original value.
I read the file as this:

```
rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///home/hadoopuser/gc/data_from_gc/part-04068",use_unicode=False)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're already reading it correctly. Just parse out the line breaks. What exactly are you doing after you read the file that's the problem?

Comment: isn't there a way of reading it as python is reading it?

Comment: Python also uses newline characters in `file.read()` and `file.readlines()`...

Comment: No, i want to read the file as it is in pyspark

Comment: And you are... I don't know what else to tell you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is probably reading the file correctly, in both cases... and in both cases, it almost assuredly contains the '\n' (newline) characters (even if you don't see them).

For example, in Python, if you use the `print()` function, any text with newline characters will display to the screen, but you won't see the actual characters, you will simply see the text, with text wrapping, as shown above.

In some tools, and PySpark may be one of them (again, not seeing your code) if you display the output of a calculation, i.e. by evaluating a Python statement using a Python prompt on the commandline versus printing the text, your result may be displayed to the screen as a string representation of the variable, which will show you the newline characters.

NOTE: If you give us the appropriate snippets of code, we can try to see where things have gone awry and provide better solutions.

For example:

```
In [4]: h = 'hello\nworld!'

In [5]: h                # Here we are simply evaluating the Python Statement
Out[5]: 'hello\nworld!'

In [6]: print(h)         # Here we are printing the content of h
hello
world!
```